# What are the requirements to fly a Mavic Mini 2 drone in the Czech Republic, Austria, and Hungary?

Tags: regulations, dji-mavic-mini, license

I am traveling to Prague, Vienna, Salzburg and Budapest. Can I fly Mavic air mini2 without permit? It's not for commercial use. Czech Republic CAA is in Czech language which I cannot read.

Answer (score 4):

Since all three countries are part of the EU, they generally follow the EU rules. I'm guessing that a valid drone pilot license from any other EU country + insurance is needed to fly legally.

From what I found on uavcoach.com, you need a permit to fly a drone in the Czech repulic, even if it's just for recreational use.
https://uavcoach.com/drone-laws-in-czech-republic/
The Czech CAA does have some info in English, you can find more here:
https://www.caa.cz/en/flight-operations/unmanned-aircraft/

Please see this discussion for more details on Prague: [How to get a licence to fly a drone in the city of Prague for a week?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/how-to-get-a-licence-to-fly-a-drone-in-the-city-of-prague-for-a-week)

Austria has a plainer implementation of the EU drone laws:
https://uavcoach.com/drone-laws-in-austria/

Hungary seems to require a special permit for any drone flights, submitted at least 30 days prior to flight:
https://uavcoach.com/drone-laws-in-hungary/